# Symfony - Show price based on Authentication Role

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, twig

I have different Authentication Roles set up in Symfony using the Security Bundle.

```
* Wholesale
* Detailing
* Public
```

Based on the authentication that the user is logged in with I want to display different prices for products.

In my Product entity I have

```
$protected wholesalePrice;
$protected detailingPrice;
$protected publicPrice;
```

Can I use one view to get the price for that specific Authentication Role or should I create 3 different views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a service and a twig extension to access it via your templates.

That way you'd only have to do something like:

```
{{ product | priceByRole }}
```

This would access your "price by role" service that handles the security logic.

Services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html
Writing a Twig Extension: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Example Twig Extension:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class PriceByRoleExtension extends \Twig_Extension implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'priceByRole' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'priceByRoleFilter'),
        );
    }

    public function priceByRoleFilter(Item $entity)
    {
        $service = $this->container->get('my.price.service');

        return $service->getPriceFromEntity($entity);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

Example Service:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product;

class PriceService
{
    protected $context;

    public function setSecurityContext(SecurityContextInterface $context = null)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getPriceFromEntity(Product $product)
    {
        if ($this->context->isGranted('ROLE_A'))
            return $product->getWholesalePrice();

        if ($this->context->isGranted('ROLE_B'))
            return $product->getDetailingPrice();

        if ($this->context->isGranted('ROLE_C'))
            return $product->getPublicPrice();

        throw new \Exception('No valid role for any price.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with only one view using `is_granted()` like this:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_A') %} 
    {{ product.wholesalePrice }}
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE B') %}
    {{ product.detailingPrice }}
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE C') %}
    {{ product.publicPrice }}
{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Alex Joyce answer is better than mine. My solution is more straightforward but if you need this role check to be in several templates you should go for the Service + Twig Extension solution.